# Best compression algorithm for CNF SAT instances in DIMACS

Tags: satisfiability, data-compression, 3-sat

For a CNF SAT instance in the DIMACS format what is the best algorithm to compress it? What is the best algorithm for 3-SAT instances in particular?

In [2020](https://satcompetition.github.io/2020/downloads/sc2020-main.uri) SAT competition used .xz which if I understand correctly relies on the LZMA algorithm.

Brotli probably would not be optimal as it has a pre-defined dictionary of English words and our text does not contain any English words.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that if you don't need to preserve whitespace, you could parse all the variables into a binary format and then compress that.

Comment: If you leave aside comments, DIMACS only needs four bits per character, yielding 50% compression without even trying.  xz gets >85% compression on large instances I tested it on, which is high even for text compression.  If you really need better performance than that, you're probably going to have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you're going to find a single answer about a single answer that is optimal for all possible 3SAT instances, so the question seems to be based on a faulty premise.

Also, what is "best" is typically a matter of opinion, as often there are multiple criteria that we can trade off (e.g., compression ratio, simplicity, speed of compression, speed of decompression), and it is a matter of personal values how you want to weight those criteria.

Comment: One certainly cannot compress better than the identity function on average over all instances but what if we ask say about the instances with a clause-variable ratio between 4.1 and 4.4?

Comment: By "best" I mean the highest compression ratio on an 4-core i5 within a minute on a 100MB file (and the uncompression should be achieved also within a minute).

Comment: @dimacs As others have stated, there isn't a once-size-fits-all solution to this. That said, in my solver benchmarker suite I use zstd to compress all problems. I analyzed the tradeoff between compression level and decompression latency over the entire corpus of SAT Comp problems, and found that zstd level 5 provided ~85% of the possible compression reachable at the highest levels, with acceptable (single digit seconds) decompression time. Going above that had radically higher decompression times for not much gain. If you want a recommendation, there ya go.